# Creating a data frame based on a simple VLOOKUP in R?

Tags: r

```
df <- iris
x <- data.frame(Petal.Length=c('1.7', '1.9', '3.5'))
```

The new data frame (dfnew) needs all 5 columns from "iris" extracted, for all the rows with the petal lengths specified in "x".

I've tried it this way, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
dfnew <- df$Petal.Length[x]
```

Comment: df[df$Petal.Length %in% x$Petal.Length, ]

Comment: @phiver: Thanks, it worked great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
> library(dplyr)
> data(iris)
> (dfnew <- iris %>% filter(Petal.Length %in% c('1.7', '1.9', '3.5')) )
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa
2          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3     setosa
3          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2     setosa
4          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5     setosa
5          4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2     setosa
6          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4     setosa
7          5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0 versicolor
8          5.7         2.6          3.5         1.0 versicolor
```

Comment: There really isn't a need for dplyr here.

Comment: Depends on personal preferences actually.

Comment: I guess. I'm just pointing out that dplyr is a bit much for the simple ask.  I wouldn't want new users to "learn" that you "need" dplyr for something as simple as filtering.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will check it out!

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that this is what you are technically asking for with "VLOOKUP", but the comment from phiver might actually be what you want.

```
df <- iris
x <- data.frame(Petal.Length=c('1.7', '1.9', '3.5'), X = c('X','Y','Z'))

df.new <- merge(df, x, by = 'Petal.Length')
```